# Could Velcro be use to install secondary glazing rather than magnets?

Tags: glazing, magnet

Does anyone know why secondary glazing (ie perspex sheets fitted inside the window) are typically connected to the windows with magnetic strips?   I'm wondering if anyone has used velcro strips instead, and what the downsides are?

Comment: What is this application for ? Is this for solar panels  ?  Just wondering never heard of it.

Comment: Velcro won't be airtight. That would seem to be prohibitive.

Comment: I have velcro-mounted window AC shroud. Velcro catches dirt that can never be removed. Also, velcro settles, the shroud never sticks exactly where I've put it, it sags few mm and then stays there. Also, magnets can be very strong but very small, while velcro is always obnoxiously big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnetic strips will, imho, separate easier compared to velcro, so subsequent removal for cleaning etc is easier.

Once you get magnets sufficiently far apart, then the force becomes much lower.